# 'sharedDispatcher' is deprecated

Tags: iphone

I've added this function.

```
- (void) registerWithTouchDispatcher {
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
}
```

error: `sharedDispatcher` is deprecated

what does it mean and what shall I do?

Answer (score 42):

Take a look at `ccDeprecated.h`, it says to use:

`[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher]`

Comment: Nice! I had no idea ccDeprecated.h even existed. Thanks for pointing this out. Wish user up there would accept your answer.

Comment: wow. thanks! i had no idea that file existed either, this helps a lot

Answer (score 16):

Change:
[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];

To:
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];

Answer (score 3):

You can check the Cocos2D code behind any Cocos (CC) method by pressing 'Shift+Command' keys and hovering on the method. Doing so on any deprecated method will take you to CCDeprecated.m which will also give you the new method.